# Shortcut keys sometimes type commands into the buffer for the file I am editing

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-coc, debugging

I'm using gvim with the included `mswin.vim` keybindings, so `Ctrl+S` AKA `C-S` will save the buffer. It provides these mappings.

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode (<C-O> doesn't work well when
" using completions).
noremap <C-S>           :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S>          <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S>          <Esc>:update<CR>gi
```

I also recently set up tab completion with [CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim). I wanted `<Esc>` to close the tab completion menu without leaving insert mode, if the menu happened to be open, so I added this binding:

```
"Make escape close the menu if visible without changing modes.
"We need to send l because otherwise we move the cursor left if we repeatedly
"esc and i for some reason.
inoremap <silent><expr> <Esc> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#close()
                            \: "\<Esc>l"
```

I now have a problem where, sometimes, in insert mode, when I hit `C-S` to save, I will get `:update`, a newline, and `gi` typed into my buffer. I think it will tend to happen if the completion menu is currently or was recently open. I suspect that these bindings are interacting to cause this problem.

Is that possible even though they are nonrecursive mappings? If so, how do I fix it? If not, how do I debug the problem? Can I get ahold of a log of what mappings are expanded so I can figure out what mapping is causing the problem?

Comment: `<Esc>` is a very special citizen that is used all over the place in Vim so it is highly recommended to not override it in any way.

Comment: Is there a way to allow `<Esc>` to dismiss a completion popup without also changing modes, without overriding its binding? Or is there a recommended keybinding that is already bound to dismissing that popup by default, that the user should just learn to use instead?

Comment: 1st question: No, `<Esc>` is best left alone. 2nd question: yes, the user should definitely learn how things work before trying random hacks. The native popup menu keybindings are documented here: `:help popupmenu-keys` and the feature is more generally documented here: `:help ins-completion`. But maybe your plugin is also overriding things? If it does, its documentation might mention it.